# Why do I receive "No such property" in before* and after* logic of domain classes in unit tests?

Tags: unit-testing, grails, mocking, grails-domain-class

I notice that any reference to a property is missing when requiring domain classes in grails unit tests.

**Somewhere in the Unit Test**

```
mockDomain(Event)

10.times {
    e   = new Event(eventCalendar:ec, title:"$ec - Event $it", details:"some detail", location:"some location", startDate: now, endDate: now+1)
    e.save()
}
```

**Event.groovy**

```
static beforeInsert = {
    if (!endDate) {
        // do something about it
    }
}
```

**Resulting error**

```
No such property: endDate for class: myproj.Event Possible solutions: endDate

groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: endDate for class: myproj.Event
Possible solutions: endDate
    at myproj.Event$__clinit__closure5.doCall(Event.groovy:74)
    at myproj.Event$__clinit__closure5.doCall(Event.groovy)
    at grails.test.MockUtils.triggerEvent(MockUtils.groovy:724)
    at grails.test.MockUtils$_addDynamicInstanceMethods_closure68.doCall(MockUtils.groovy:752)
    at grails.test.MockUtils$_addDynamicInstanceMethods_closure68.doCall(MockUtils.groovy)
    at myproj.EventCalendarTest$_testCreateAndDeleteCalendarWithEvents_closure1.doCall(EventCalendarTest.groovy:43)
    at myproj.EventCalendarTest.testCreateAndDeleteCalendarWithEvents(EventCalendarTest.groovy:40)
```

1. **How can I still create a working test?**
2. **Why is the stacktrace suggesting the property which it has stated as
   missing?**

Comment: Fisrt thing - is `ednDate` spelled correctly? Are you using `mockDomain()`? If yes, it must be a bug in `mockDomain()` implementation.

Comment: I've added some more code from the test - including the mockDomain() statement. Spelling is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've incorrectly defined your event handler as a static closure:

```
static beforeInsert = {
    if (!endDate) {
        // do something about it
    }
}
```

You can't access `endDate` here because it's (presumably) a non-static property. Change your event handler to be non-static and your problem should be fixed.

```
def beforeInsert = {
    if (!endDate) {
        // do something about it
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Don! Replacing "static" by a simple "def" resolved the issue. I wonder why it hadn't occured in normal use (run-app)? Also, is there a reason for setting this to "static" (the code is from another programmer)?

Comment: The other programmer made a mistake, event handlers must be non-static. My guess is that the handler was never called "in normal use", but you didn't notice.

Comment: Just did some manual tests. The handler is being called regardless of being "static". It is in the code of the app at least 3 times, thus I am wondering ...

Comment: I just noticed that the ones with `static` were defined as closures (`static beforeDelete = {}`) while the ones with `def` are methods (`def beforeDelete() {}`).